# I accidentally deleted a ipynb notebook in Vertex AI workbench. How can I recover it back?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, data-science, recovery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I just got the history of all the commands I ran before on Vertex AI. But not able to recover the specific file.

Comment: So have you checked the backup?

Comment: There is no backup option visible on the Vertex AI workbench.

Comment: Can you duplicate your files on your computer>? that would be a simple backup...

Comment: But how to recover the ones that are already deleted?